# How can I remove my street address from my Chrome Web Store listing?

Tags: chrome-web-store

My extension is published in the CWS, but the listing includes my home address. How can I remove my address from the store display? I noticed many other extensions don't display the developer address. My extension is offered for free, so there's no in-app purchase issue. I live in the EU, if that makes any difference.