# How can I hide my street address from my chrome web store extension listing?

Tags: chrome-web-store

I was asked to fill it when creating my account (or when uploading my first item, can't remember), but now when it is published my street address is publicly visible to everyone? This seems pretty wrong an I surely don't want it to be available for everyone.
When going to the address in my account, I can only edit it, and I can't leave fields like city and street blank.
There isn't a delete option.

Surely google can't be expecting me to share my personal home address with the world?
I looked at other listings and couldn't see the address, so there must be a way. What am I missing?

Surprisingly the only question about this I found here is this one with no answers:
[How can I remove my street address from my Chrome Web Store listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74120039/how-can-i-remove-my-street-address-from-my-chrome-web-store-listing)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my account was set to trader. Once I've changed it to non-trader I could delete my address.